# Pull a post based on a meta value in a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, meta-query, metabox

I'm trying to display a post, from a custom post type based on a meta value in that post type, in this case a checkbox that says "if this is checked show it on the front page.

Usually I write a query using meta_key = > front_event value => true. But this does not work for custom post types.

So I have this:

```
<?php 
    $event =array(
    'post_type' => 'Events',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'order' =>'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array( array(
            'key' => 'front_event',
            'value' => true ))
    );?>
```

This also does not work. Can anyone tell me what I should be doing differently?

Thank you!

Nadine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap `true` with quotes

```
<?php 
$event =array(
'post_type' => 'Events',
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'meta_query' => array( array(
        'key' => 'front_event',
        'value' => 'true' ))
);?>
```

Comment: That totally worked. See, that one piece of syntax would have driven me nuts for a while. :) Thank you Asel! 

Nadine